# How to Rotate ellipse using single touch in WPF

Tags: wpf, math

Any idea how to Rotate an ellipse by single finger touch?

Here is my code:

```
private Point currentPoint;

private void MyEllips_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{

    // RotateMe.Angle =
}

private void MyEllips_OnTouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    currentPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;

}
```

How to calculate touch point angle while moving?

[image]

Comment: UIElements can be rotated by using `RenderTransform` is that what ur looking for ?

Comment: I know this , but i need to rotate any circle using one touch finger 

example : casino roller 

http://i.stack.imgur.com/MzSbG.png

Comment: If the center is a fixed point in the gauge, just do the trigonometry? Each of those digits displayed is at some angle. Then use RenderTransform as suggested.